# High Side Switching Inductive Load with MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, power-electronics, mosfet-driver

I am attempting to make a PCB that high-side switches an inductive load (water pump) that draws 4.6A peak. The switching scheme will not include any PWM, just basic on/off functionality.

My concern is clamping the voltage spikes from the load during turn-off. I want to avoid going into avalanche mode on the MOSFET to ensure maximum reliability as the board will be operating in temperatures of 80-90 C ambient.

The MOSFET I am considering is [here](https://static6.arrow.com/aropdfconversion/519c4bbd273bd9437146758adb3b4e9ded299485/2966ipd122n10n3g_rev2.2.pdffileiddb3a30432239cccd0122604a0b2e7f65fold.pdf) and I am looking at [this](https://static6.arrow.com/aropdfconversion/ae4600d2113a65c5f885e8a49384fa80e4ef6ea6/infineon-irs2127pbf-datasheet-v02_00-en.pdf) gate driver.

My current circuit idea is shown below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9UwFn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

D2 will conduct below the maximum Vds of the MOSFET, during switch off of the load where the source voltage will go negative.

I am less confident in the behavior of D1. My intention with D1 is to conduct during shut off of the load, so that Vgs does not exceed the maximum allowable. My uncertainty stems from the gate driver - how will it behave in this scenario?

Comment: D1 just acts as a voltage clamp for the gate-source junction to tame funny business from high dV/dT working its way through parasitics. It is not always required.

Comment: Regarding the gate driver, what parameter will tell me the most negative source voltage that it can maintain Vgs of 0V for?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/application-note/AN90001.pdf   page 11 of this doc states "Vs will go negative until current flow is maintained, however the source is tied firmly to the gate by the driver which is operating at 0 V."

Comment: Are you just asking what the gate driver's minimum Vs is under absolute maximum rating in the datasheet? Or Note 1 at the bottom of the page?

Comment: yes, the minimum Vs for the gate driver is what I am trying to determine

Comment: The gate driver uses a bootstrap for the high side drive, how are you going to maintain the high side drive voltage?  Do you have an isolated supply in place of the bootstrap circuit?  Otherwise you won't be able to keep the FET on.

Comment: @JohnD I'll be using the bootstrap circuit shown in the gate driver datasheet

Comment: @JohnD It's buried but the OP does provide a link to their gate driver.

Comment: @DKNguyen Thanks, I saw that, but the driver he selected uses a bootstrap technique to drive the gate above the drain voltage.  That means it relies on the bootstrap cap voltage being refreshed on a regular basis.  If you want to turn the FET on and leave it on it won't work.  The OP states that there's no PWM involved so I assume he's using the FET as an ON/OFF switch, which will be problematic.

Comment: @JohnD How can I perform the high side switching without running into this issue? I only have access to the 12v in this application.

Comment: @NithinVedamuthu If you are just using it as a switch (100% duty cycle so the source never goes to ground for the cap to refresh) then you need to replace the bootstrap cap and diode with a small isolated supply like an isolated regulator. or add a 555 as a floating charge pump to continuously refresh the cap while on.

Comment: page 17 https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-HV_Floating_MOS_Gate_Drivers-AN-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153559f7cf21200

Answer (score 2, accepted):

L1 should have a freewheel diode across it .Any fast diode will work .It is not good to allow negative backswing on the fragile highside driver chip .The freewheel diode also ensures that M1 will not see much more than 12VDC .

Answer (score 1):

This is all the protection you need

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkalEc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

D_Freewheel prevents the output of the inductor from going more than 1v below ground. It's got to be able to handle the full current that the motor takes. Even 'slow' diodes like 1N540x are quite sufficient, they're only slow on turnoff, they turn on quickly enough for this application.

You'll notice I've drawn it directly across the inductor terminals. This is intended to show that I'm minimising the area enclosed by the inductor-diode loop. If you grounded the diode at some distance from the motor ground, the excess inductance comprised of that loop may still give you trouble.

D2 was completely superfluous.

D1 is a reasonable precaution to have anyway, FET gates are fragile things.

Comment: I have long leads going from the pcb to the motor so this isn't possible for my case

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution better suited to my application:
https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MC33981.pdf

Comment: That should work as it includes a built-in charge pump  along with the bootstrap cap so you can have 100% duty cycle operation.